# C# DataGridViewButtonCell set buttons text

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewbuttoncolumn

I need to add my `DataGridViewButtonCell` to `Column`, and I need to name each other with different names.

**But I didn't find any text properties.**

Can anyone help me, please?

i do that stuff

```
DataGridViewButtonCell b = new DataGridViewButtonCell(); 
b.Value = "name"; 
MainTable.Rows.Add(b);
```

and it doesn't work

Comment: If you set the DataGridViewCell.Value property as most answers suggest it will change the actual Value. Often not acceptable. Use the CellFormatting event and set the e.Value there!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I admit that I don't understand *why* your method wouldn't work, but I was able to get the following to do what you wanted as a work-around:

```
        DataGridViewButtonCell b = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
        int rowIndex = MainTable.Rows.Add(b);
        MainTable.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value = "name";
```

In my example I'm assuming you only have one column (a DataGridViewButtonColumn).  You should be able to modify this however you like so long as you set the value *after* you add the row.  Again, not sure why that's the case...

Answer (score 51):

If you want all the buttons to have same text use [UseColumnTextForButtonValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn.usecolumntextforbuttonvalue.aspx) property.

If you want different text for each button then use [DataGridViewCell.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value.aspx) property

Comment: UseColumnTextForButtonValue was exactly what I wanted. Set it true and set the column's Text property to what you want displayed.

Comment: When UseColumnTextForButtonValue is false and the gridview VirtualMode is true then the column needs to be databound for the text to display, unless you subclass the buttoncell and override the Value(GetValue/SetValue) then set it as the cell template on the column.

Answer (score 21):

If you want to set the same text for all buttons, you can:

1. In `GridView` properties click on edit columns
2. Click on your button column
3. Set `Text` to the text you want to see on each button
4. Set `UserColumnTextForButtonValue` to `True`

See below:

[image: Edit Button Column]

Answer (score 6):

I know you got your answer accepted but I added these in `constructor` and it worked for me. The only thing I was missing is `UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true`

```
public Form1() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var editColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn
        {
            Text = "Edit",
            UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true,
            Name = "Edit",
            DataPropertyName = "Edit"
        };
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(editColumn);
    }
```

Comment: that's nice answer, I solved it long time ago, but that's the best if it really works, can't check it for myself, but anyone looking for an answer better try this

Answer (score 5):

Use this to show the same text on all buttons with default button at first

```
DataGridView.Columns["Buttons_Index"].DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "name";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try example given in below link.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncolumn.usecolumntextforbuttonvalue.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
yourDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value
```

Comment: i do that stuff

    `DataGridViewButtonCell b = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
    b.Value = "name";
    MainTable.Rows.Add(b);`

and it doesn't work

Comment: just button column, thats all

Comment: You also need add DataGridViewButtonColumn to table
DataGridViewButtonColumn column =
            new DataGridViewButtonColumn ();
        column.Name = "Buttons";
        MainTable.Columns.Add(column);

Answer (score 0):

you looking for [DataGridViewCell.Value Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value.aspx)

Comment: i do that stuff DataGridViewButtonCell b = new DataGridViewButtonCell(); b.Value = "name"; MainTable.Rows.Add(b); and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you have just one column and that's a buttoncolumn by default

```
MainTable.Rows.Add("Some text");
```

will suffice.

Comment: hopes it will help smbdy who use just one column.

Comment: yeah actually. one who uses just one button column for a whole dgv might need a lot of help 8)

Answer (score -1):

[Colimn.Name].Text = "Click Me"

[Colimn.Name].UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True

[button_Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.%20datagridviewbuttoncolumn.usecolumntextforbuttonvalue?redirectedfrom=%20MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewButtonColumn_%20UseColumnTextForButtonValue)
Use this code in Form_Load event-it will name all buttons in that column as  "Click Me".