# Changing DataGridView button text windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button inside `DataGridView` as:

```
  var dgvButCol = new DataGridViewDisableButtonColumn()
            {
                Name = "btnSetContact",
                Text = "Set Contact",
                HeaderText = "Set",
                UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true
            };
```

As you see, I have `UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true` because I want to change the text after. In order to change it I try:

```
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvDeliveryBreakdownDesignGroup.Rows)
            {
                bool.TryParse(row.Cells["HaveDeliveryContact"].Value.ToString(), out bool haveDeliveryContact);

                if (haveDeliveryContact || lblDeliveryContactName.Text == "None")
                {
                   
                    ((DataGridViewDisableButtonColumn)row.Cells["btnSetContact"]).Text = "gg";

                }

}
```

But it throws an error:

> Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell' to
> 'MyProjectName.Controls.DataGridViewDisableButtonColumn'

How can I access Text property casting something like: `DataGridViewDisableButtonCell` (this do not have Text property but I can select row inside foreach)

Comment: Yes, the exception is clear, you are doing a wrong cast. Also, not clear if you want to change the `Value` of a single or some buttons or all of them. All buttons will display what you assigned to the `Text` property when you enable the `UseColumnTextForButtonValue` property. So, what are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the property of a column that is a button to `UseColumnTextForButtonValue = false;` Adjust it in DataGridView

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvDeliveryBreakdownDesignGroup.Rows)
{
   DataGridViewButtonCell buttonCell = (DataGridViewButtonCell)row.Cells[0];
   buttonCell.Value = "button row " + row.Index;
}
```

Follow this link to set *[UseColumnTextForButtonValue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47133782/15019536)*